# Can I show only a part of my heatmap e.g. the upper part?

Tags: r, heatmap, pheatmap

I have a big dataset with around 1000 significant hits calculated by anova.
I can draw a beautiful heatmap using the pheatmap package.
However, the heatmap is huge and I would like to look at bigger clusters in more detail.
Can I somehow hide parts of the heatmap?

I have extracted clusters using cutree and made a heatmap with those. However, since part of the data is missing, the clustering is different.
I really just want to hide the upper/lower/left/right part instead of recalculating the clustering with part of the data.

Let's say for example I have this pheatmap:

```
data(iris)
iris_heatmap <- iris[-5] %>% scale()
iris_heatmap <- iris_heatmap %>% as.data.frame()
pheatmap(as.matrix(iris_heatmap))
```

but instead of the whole picture being shown I only want to see this:
[image: cut pheatmap]

I just dont want to cut the picture myself but have R do it.

Many thanks for your help!!

Comment: Maybe output as jpeg then crop it, `magick::image_crop` , see https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magick/vignettes/intro.html

Comment: Thank you for your idea! This is an option but therefore I would need to actually know where to cut by pixel (as far as I understood). I would rather like to define where to cut by defining the clusters I want to show to maybe also be able to cut something out in the middle. Plus, I would loose all the information around it such as annotation of the columns if I cut at the wrong site.